# Is Stewie Griffin gay?

Tags: family-guy

Is Stewie Griffin gay?

*Disclaimer: I will try not to offend any LGBT+ people out there reading this post. I am openly gay myself and it is not intended to insult anyone*

Throughout the show, it seems to make hints at it such as in "The Old Man and the Big C" and in [this](https://youtu.be/15uO8Za5Wc4) clip where Stewie displays some very camp and stereotypically "gay" tendencies.

However there is the very obvious fact the Stewie is only 1 years old and hasn't hit puberty yet. Meaning that he shouldn't yet know his sexual orientation.

This seems like a well-known thing and I'm surprised I haven't found a question about this. The last I read, Seth MacFarlane hadn't yet confirmed or denied this.

Also, if he is gay, how? As I pointed out above, he hasn't yet hit puberty.

Comment: you don't need to hit puberty to show signs of any sexual orientation/preference. generally it's a little bit before or during puberty we're taught about that stuff and in Stewie's case he's a genius since he knows how sex works (eg, he went into Peter and destroyed almost all his sperm to prevent a brother) and he created a time machine

Comment: A timemachine by killing sperm???? WOW.

Comment: I'm not gay, but I definitely started to explore my sexuality well before I hit puberty.  (Not as young as Stewie, granted, but I certainly wouldn't say it's impossible to start thinking about such things before puberty.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. By 2009 it was known, but not explicitly stated in the show. It still hasnt in a decade after.  According to creator Seth:

http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/gossip/seth-macfarlane-outs-baby-stewie-family-guy-gay-macfarlane-playboy-interview-article-1.395390

> "We had an episode that went all the way to the script phase in which Stewie does come out,” MacFarlane,  the show’s creator, says in the September [2009] issue of Playboy magazine. “It had to do with the harassment he took from other kids at school. He ends up going back in time to prevent a passage in Leviticus from being written: ‘Thou shalt not lie with mankind as with womankind. It is an abomination.’
>
> ***"But we decided it’s better to keep it vague, which makes more sense because he’s a 1-year-old. Ultimately, Stewie will be gay or a very unhappy repressed heterosexual.*** It also explains why he’s so hellbent on killing [his mother, Lois] and taking over the world: He has a lot of aggression, which comes from confusion and uncertainty about his orientation."

As to how a 1 year old could be that before puberty,  consider he talks, can build super science machines, and is a caricature, a satire on society in a cartoon...

Comment: Playboy has/had decades of interviews for non-sex things that men would be interested in.

Comment: Everybody reads it for the articles. Didn't you know?